# How display image once?

Tags: java, android

May be need to keep some value in SharedPreferences?

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/fragment2_bacground" 
  android:foreground="@drawable/fragment2">
```

**Class**

```
FrameLayout frameLayout;
frameLayout = (FrameLayout)rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.fragment2_bacground);

prefs = getActivity.getSharedPreferences("com.example.potehki.potehki", getActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This method does not work

```
if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) { 
 frameLayout .setforeground(null);
 prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit(); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using setForeground.

I will suggest to keep exactly the same logic just change from FrameLayout to ImageView (with src attribute) and instead of using frameLayout:

setforeground(null);

Use:

imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) { 
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit(); 
}

That is how it should be?

Comment: yes and right before : imageView = (ImageView)rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.[imageViewId]);